# Laravel 5.8 Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get($id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id)

Tags: php, laravel

Just After I Upgraded my php to PHP 7.4 I'm now getting this error,

```
Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get($id) must be compatible with 
Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id)
/home/forge/myapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 15
```

I've tried to run Composer Update But it's Still now Working what could be the problem and How do I fix this.

Comment: Try with this command `command composer self --1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get($id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526288/declaration-of-illuminate-container-containergetid-must-be-compatible-with)

Comment: I'm just from their and I can't seem to get the answer

Comment: @EsTeAa I have Tried that and its still the same

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526288/declaration-of-illuminate-container-containergetid-must-be-compatible-with

Comment: @HedayatullahSarwary The solution provided is not working

Comment: It's a know issue (https://github.com/php-fig/container/issues/30) but psr\container version 1.1.1 on PHP7.4 should fix the problem.

Comment: Remove your composer cache `composer clearcache` , delete your `vendor` folder and then run `composer install`

Comment: @DimitriMostrey Checked this file its exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem was after upgrading PHP I had to update the nginx vhost at
`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_vhost` 
by changing the old PHP7.1-fpm.sock to PHP7.4-fpm.sock
From

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
   
    }
```

To

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your composer cache by the command below:

```
composer clearcache
```

Then remove the vendor folder and run `composer install`. I hope this solution help you.

Comment: deleting it's taking some time

Comment: See this link it will not help you: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/