# Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get($id)

Tags: laravel, vercel

I have a Laravel 9 project

I am trying to deploy the project to ***Vercel***

But every time I deploy it I get the following message

> Fatal error: Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::get(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get($id) in /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 702

I tried following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526288/declaration-of-illuminate-container-containergetid-must-be-compatible-with)

But it didn't work since some dependencies in Laravel 9 needs psr/container >= 1.1.1